# When an automatic update of the Microsoft Teams Windows client is performed, where are these updated files saved?

Tags: windows, updates, microsoft-teams, software-update

I've just launched the Windows build of the Microsoft Teams client on a machine that hasn't had it running since the end of last year. After several seconds, the application restarted and presented me with the updated client interface that I was expecting - however, when checking all files within the Teams installation folder (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams) all files still had a modification date of last year.

So - my question. If this is the case and that the Teams client is in fact being run from the above location when launched (confirmed by checking the "Command Line" column of Task Manager), which location are updated files downloaded to?

Comment: Are the files in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current` and `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\previous` have the same modification dates? Did the update complete successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Teams has a weird way of updating files.

It first deletes all files in the folder and then extracts the files from an archive.

When it comes to modification date, when a file is created on an NTFS drive, only the creation date is set, not the modification date. The modification date is when Microsoft changed the file in their dev environment.

By default, the creation date of the file is not shown in details view, but can be made visible. If you look at that date, you'll see that it corresponds with the time/date of the update.